# if statement not running calculation on wix, am I missing something obvious?

Tags: javascript, velo

I'm a beginner and can't figure out why my if statements aren't working. Im using wixcode and javascript. Each if statement below shows a different way I have tried to get the calculation to run. The number that is input as SR is displayed in the textbox onClick but doesn't run the calculation to manipulate the input number, Or maybe it is not running the if statements all together. Am I missing something obvious?

```
    $w.onReady(function () {
$w("#generatequote").onClick((event) => {

    var SR = $w("#SR").value;
    if (SR<100) {
        $w("#SR").value = SR *2
        //example one. Tried making it write the input * 2 if the input number is less than 100
    }
    else if (SR>=100&&SR<300) {
        $w("#SR").value = ("#SR")*1.5;
        //example two. Tried making it write the input * 1.5 if the input number is between 100 and 300
    }
    else if (SR>=300&&SR<600) {
        $w("#SR").value * 1.25;
        //example three. Tried making it write the input * 1.25 if the input is between 300 and 600
    }
    else if(SR>=600) {
        $w("#SR").value = ("SR");
    }

    $w("#quotetext").value =(SR)
```

Comment: Does it run none of the statements? Does the `onClick` even work?

Comment: I hope you have the matching }) at the end of your code, as it is not shown in your example

Comment: The onClick does work, but it runs none of the statements. I do have the }) at the end of the code, i just forgot to include it in the example because it comes after a bunch of notes to myself. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` returned is in `string` format and your if statement is comparing with `numbers` because of which none of your `if` statements evaluates to truthy value. First convert the input value in `number/integer` type and then make comparison

```
var SR = Number($w("#SR").value);
```